# css transform scale not working in safari

Tags: css, safari

Please excuse my terrible formatting. I'm trying to understand why transform scale isn't working in Safari.

What I've got is four boxes in alternating burgandy and grey, and I have them swap colour and enlarge when hovered over to make it clearer which one is being highlighted.

I've been developing from chrome ver. 41.0.2272.89 dev-m and I can see it working in the other browsers that I've tested in. (Firefox; and ie 9/10).

I've found it somewhat works on a colleagues' safari in that I can see the buttons enlarging but the animation is very choppy and unfortunately I haven't had the chance to check what version he is using.

```
/* background transition */

#block-block-7 .content .four.columns:nth-child(1) a { background:#a20055;}
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns:nth-child(2) a { background:#696a6e;}
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns:nth-child(3) a { background:#a20055;}
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns:nth-child(4) a { background:#696a6e;}
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns a:hover { background:#696a6e; }
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns:nth-child(2) a:hover { background:#a20055;}
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns:nth-child(4) a:hover { background:#a20055;}

/*reduces size before hover to reduce overlaps and enhance effect */

#block-block-7 .content .four.columns a, 
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns a,
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns a, 
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns a  { transform: scale(0.9);
-ms-transform: scale (0.9);
-webkit-transform:scale(0.9);
-moz-transform: scale(0.9);
-o-transform: scale(0.9);
}

/*expand on hover */

#block-block-7 .content .four.columns a:hover, 
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns a:hover,
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns a:hover, 
#block-block-7 .content .four.columns a:hover  { transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale (1.1);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: write only the relevant code not all the css selectors.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time, first time poster. Sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scale specifies two parameters for webkit-transform, try:

```
-webkit-transform:scale(0.9, 0.9);
```

Comment: @shojiin Sweet! Not sure why one parameter worked in some versions of Safari but not the others, but glad it works now.

Comment: Doesn't work for now. Not sure if they changed something on the newer version ?

Comment: @SandipSubedi should still work. Do you have an example up that we can take a look at? This link has some great documentation to get you started on transform, and values. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: The answer is good. Since Safari supports scale, you'll need to do add it as well like this as a fallback:

-webkit-transform:scale(0.9, 0.9);
transform:scale(0.9, 0.9);

It is documented in CanIUse as Safari Technology Preview: https://caniuse.com/?search=scale